# Read zip example in readme.md - undefined local variable or method `dest_file' for main:Object (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubyzip

Implementing the example code in ready.md, I get the error above. Searching through the source I can't find a method `dest_file`. The code I've implemented -

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'zip'

Zip::File.open('test.zip') do |zip_file|
  # Handle entries one by one
  zip_file.each do |entry|
    # Extract to file/directory/symlink
    puts "Extracting #{entry.name}"
    entry.extract(dest_file)

    # Read into memory
    content = entry.get_input_stream.read
  end
end
```

Have I understood this incorrectly? My assumption is that `dest_file` give the file the right metadata so it can be saved, but replacing with obvious `entry.name` throws an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `dest_file` value.  You need to specify the file name.  May be you can use:

```
 entry.extract(entry.name)
```

to extract the file with same name as source file name and in the current directory.

---

If you want to extract to a specific dir, then, you could do something like below:

```
require "zip"

output_dir = "/tmp/"

Zip::File.open('a.zip') do |zip_file|
  # Handle entries one by one
  zip_file.each do |entry|
    # Extract to file/directory/symlink
    puts "Extracting #{entry.name}"
    entry.extract("#{File.expand_path(output_dir)}/#{entry.name}")
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi - I did look at that, but when you use entry.name with or without path you get `entry.rb:582:in `initialize': No such file or directory - OPS/chapter-1.xhtml (Errno::ENOENT)` - which is what made me think that dest_file is a method.

Comment: I'm just looking at entry.rb - initialize to see fi I can work out what's going on.....

Comment: Not sure what is the issue in your case, I have tested above suggestions before posting.  They extract the files from a zip file.

Comment: Hi - have just discovered the problem - I'm extracting an ePub, not a zip - had assumed they worked the same way, but they don't. Apologies.

Comment: ....however, the issue you've answered is valid for a normal zip file - so thank you  :)